# How to create or integrate paypal payment gateway in cakephp

Tags: paypal

I have a product which was created in cakephp. There are no payment gateway to process purchase. So i need paypal ,moneybooker payment gateway plugin to install in cakephp. can anyone help me..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step guide which explains hot to integrate PayPal in PHP.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/webtechnick/2009/08/11/paypal-ipn-instant-payment-notification-plugin-complete-with-paypalhelper

http://neeocis.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/cakephp-component-for-paypal-intergration-with-socket/

https://neeocis.wordpress.com/tag/cakephp-paypal-integration/

http://www.dollarfry.com/paypal-integration-guide-php/

hope this helps

CakePHP and paypal integration plugin.

http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/218/CakePHP_Paypal_IPN_Plugin

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cpierce/2013/09/11/plugin_for_paypal_web_payments_pro_for_cake_php_2_x

https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Paypal-IPN-Plugin

https://github.com/daniula/CakePHP-2.0-Paypal-IPN-Plugin

Comment: I have knowledge in paypal integration in this provided way. But I am asking to make this in cake php. Is there any plugin to integrate ?

Comment: Yes there are plugins.. I have listed in my answer by updating the answer.. please check